# Сумма n первых натуральных чисел и сумма от (n-1)

Tags: математика, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, можете подсказать откуда выводится формула из 2 строчки. В 1 понятно это сумма первых нат. чисел, но почему во 2 формуле появляется минус в скобках? Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вторая же формула - это первая минус (n-1)... Что такое сумма единиц от 2 до n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вот и все - текст нужен только чтоб 30 символов набрать :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Впрочем, вот еще одно пояснение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! А формула для суммы единиц  получается просто подстановкой единицы в формулу?

Comment: Ну да, сумма единиц в количестве n-1 штука :)

Answer (score 1):

Тут всё просто расписать и получить

`summ _ j=2 ^n (j-1) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n-1` а это арифметическая прогрессия `n*(n-1)/2`

Answer (score 0):

и формулу 1) и формулу 2) можно доказать с помощью математической индукции

1. проверим верность при `n = 2`: `sum = j - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1 = 2(2-1)/2 = 1` - верно
2. пусть формула верна при n, проверим ее при `k = n + 1`, получаем

   ```
    n(n-1)/2 + n = (k-1)(k-2)/2 + (k - 1) = (k^2 -3k + 2 = 2k - 2)/2 = k(k-1)/2 - верно
   ```

формула доказана

Comment: спасибо за помощь !